# Reinterpret cast for pointer of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

I have two classes: a `Parent` class and a `Child` class (inheriting from the `Parent` class). I would like to know if it is possible to cast/transform a `Child**` to a  `Parent**` with `reinterpret_cast` or something else. Is such a thing possible?

Below is a minimal example. I am wondering is that code correct, or `Child**` to a  `Parent**` "transformation" is not correct and should not be attempted?

**NB:** my question is on the conversion of the pointer of pointer, i.e., is this line correct?

```
Parent** ptrToChildPtr = reinterpret_cast<Parent**>(&childPtr);
```

I know that the pointer deletion could be done in a much simpler way. I just want to show here the conversion I want to perform, if such conversion is possible.

Many thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
    virtual ~Parent() {
        std::cout << "Destructor of Parent class" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child() {}
    virtual ~Child() {
        std::cout << "Destructor of Child class" << std::endl;
    }
};

void deletePointer(Parent** ptr) {
  if (*ptr) {
    delete *ptr;
    *ptr = nullptr;
  }
}

int main() {
  Child* childPtr = new Child();
  Parent** ptrToChildPtr = reinterpret_cast<Parent**>(&childPtr);

  std::cout << "Before delete function: childPtr = " << childPtr << std::endl;
  deletePointer(ptrToChildPtr);
  std::cout << "After delete function: childPtr = " << childPtr << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Edit (suggested)

Maybe providing a more concrete example as to why I would like to transform some pointers because the answers I got are not really answering the core of the issue

I have a code (not coded by me and I cannot change its structure it is too big) where basically a lot of raw pointers of different types `Child1`, `Child2`, ... `ChildN` inheriting from `Parent` class are initialized (so using `new`... and thus should be deleted with `delete`)

At different moments in the code I would need to delete those pointers and initialize either all of them or few of them again. Which is painful to track so I would like to have a  `PointerHandler` class that takes care of initializing and deleting those pointers calling respectively the `initPointer()` and `deleteAllPointers` function (as shown below) but so for that I would need to store the addess of pointers holders within the `PointerHandler` class hence the question about transforming addresses

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent(const std::string & name): m_name(name) {}
    virtual ~Parent()  {
        std::cout << "Deleter of Parent class name=" << m_name << std::endl;
    }
    protected: 
      std::string m_name;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
  public:
    Child1(const std::string & name): Parent(name) {}
    virtual ~Child1() {
        std::cout << "Deleter of Child1 class for name=" << m_name << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
  public:
    Child2(const std::string & name): Parent(name) {}
    virtual ~Child2() {
        std::cout << "Deleter of Child2 class for name=" << m_name << std::endl;
    }
};


class PointerHandler{
  public: 
    PointerHandler(){}
    ~PointerHandler(){ deleteAllPointers(); }

    // Template function to init the pointers
    template<class TChildClass> 
    void initPointer(const std::string &name, TChildClass * &childPtr){
      // Init the child pointer 
      childPtr = new TChildClass(name);

      // Keep track of the pointer adress so that it can be deleted 
      Parent** ptrToChildPtr = reinterpret_cast<Parent**>(&childPtr);
      m_vecPtrs.push_back(ptrToChildPtr);
    }

    void deleteAllPointers(){
      // Delete all pointers and reset pointer holder to nullptr 
      for (Parent **ptr: m_vecPtrs){
        deleterFunction(ptr);
      }
      m_vecPtrs.clear();
    }

  private: 
    std::vector<Parent**> m_vecPtrs;
    // Function used to delete pointers
    void deleterFunction(Parent** ptr) {
      if (*ptr){
        delete *ptr;
        *ptr = nullptr;
      }
    }
};

int main() {

  // Define pointer handler 
  PointerHandler ptrHdr;

  // Pointers to child classes 
  Child1* child1_0 = nullptr;
  Child1* child1_1 = nullptr;
  Child2* child2_0 = nullptr;
  Child2* child2_1 = nullptr;

  // Initialize pointers 
  ptrHdr.initPointer("child1_0", child1_0);
  ptrHdr.initPointer("child1_1", child1_1);
  ptrHdr.initPointer("child2_1", child2_0);
  ptrHdr.initPointer("child2_1", child2_1);

  std::cout << "Before deletion" << std::endl ;
  std::cout << "child1_0 ptr = " << child1_0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "child1_1 ptr = " << child1_1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "child2_1 ptr = " << child2_0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "child2_1 ptr = " << child2_1 << std::endl;

  // Delete all pointers 
  ptrHdr.deleteAllPointers();

  std::cout << "After deletion" << std::endl ;
  std::cout << "child1_0 ptr = " << child1_0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "child1_1 ptr = " << child1_1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "child2_1 ptr = " << child2_0 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "child2_1 ptr = " << child2_1 << std::endl;

  // Init only few now poiters
  ptrHdr.initPointer("child1_0", child1_0);
  ptrHdr.initPointer("child1_1", child1_1);

  // deletion will occur when pointer handler is going out of scope

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code looks legal to me, are you having any problems?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is never illegal. It's what you do with the pointer afterwards that counts, i.e. what the type of the pointer is, compared to what the pointer is really pointing to.

Comment: @john I do not have any issue. But I want to make sure this is fine because I saw the `reinterpret_cast` can be trciky to use hence I prefer asking to experts here rather than assuming things work :)

Comment: Well you start with `Child*` and you end with `Parent*` and since deleting a child object via a parent pointer when the parent type has a virtual destructor is OK, so this code is OK. Like I said it's not the `reinterpret_cast` that is legal or illegal, it's what happens afterwards that is the issue.

Comment: Okay okay perfect then thanks a lot @john,
what I was not sure is that if it was fine to reinterpret a pointer of pointer  

The code here contains basically what I want to do in a more complicated code. 
I just want to keep track of the `Child**` and store them in a `std::vector<Parent**>` to then delete them when I want to. 
So if that looks good it's all I need :)

Comment: @john No it is not ok. This is punning `Child*` as `Parent*`, which is definitely not ok.

Comment: sorry I missed a `*` in my previous message

Comment: When you're casting in an inheritance hierarchy, you should **never** be using `reinterpret_cast`. If `static_cast` doesn't work, then you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @PasserBy so this is not ok to you? `Parent** ptrToChildPtr = reinterpret_cast<Parent**>(&childPtr);`

Comment: Reading a `Child*` as a `Parent*` is UB, which is what `reinterpret_cast` does.

Comment: @PasserBy I am a bit confused is it not what we do if one does `Parent* myPtr = new Child();` and then use `myPtr`? `myPtr` is of type `Parent*` but you can still get the function/objects from the child class using virtual functions 
Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257115/discussion-between-passer-by-and-romain-bqt4).

Comment: Whenever you write code that depends on a cast to a derived pointer you have a desing issue. Your Parent class should have a virtual method that your Child class implements (or overrides, it is ok for baseclass to do nothing). And then you call the virtual method WITHOUT casting. Side note : you are still using `new/delete` so I gues you have not read the latest C++ guidelines yet. At least use std::make_unique. (https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)

Comment: @PasserBy You state : *When you're casting in an inheritance hierarchy*. Casting should hardly ever be necessary with the proper design

Comment: Hi @PepijnKramer please find below a more concrete example I wish I could use smart pointers but within the code I use it is not possible because it would imply changing way to much code ^^"

Comment: Reinterpret_cast is generally a bad idea, because it can't adjust pointer addresses as you go up and down the inheritance tree.  For an example see https://godbolt.org/z/z3sxG7YMP

Comment: Because of **multiple inheritance** the `reinterpret_cast` is a loaded footgun.  (And using it in the way as being done here is **undefined behavior**, even if it seems to work.)  Granted, the OP code does not use multiple inheritance — but adding it into the mix makes it easy to trip UB (as seen by UBSan).

Comment: Alright many thanks everyone that was precisely my question to understand if `reinterpret_cast` was doing what I expected or no. Answer is thus No so I won't use that code

Comment: Slightly OT, but it's 2024... why are you still using raw pointers?

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade because I use an old code used by different groups of person so I can't chnage evrything the way I would like there are things we can't change without impacting a lot of persons... + the code is not that trivial to change

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `reinterpret_cast` completely, if you use an intermittent `Parent *`:

```
Child* childPtr = new Child();
Parent* parentPtr = childPtr;        // No cast necessary!
Parent** ptrToChildPtr = &parentPtr;
```

Furthermore, if you don't need the `Child*`, because you do all manipulations and access through virtual methods of the parent, then you can leave out the `Child*` from your code and directly assign the newly created `Child` to a `Parent*`:

```
Parent* new_child = new Child();
Parent** ptrToChildPtr = &parentPtr;
```

Note, though, that using double pointers in C++ is rare. In most cases, they can and should be completely avoided. In particular, use smart pointers to automatically delete an object and the pointer to it together, instead of keeping pointers around. So, a different and much easier structure to achieve, what you are doing, might be:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> children;

// add children as needed
children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child1>("child1_0"));
children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child1>("child1_1"));
children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child2>("child2_0"));
children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child2>("child2_1"));

// cleanup:
children.clear();

// re-add data:
children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child1>("child1_processed_0"));
children.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Child1>("child1_processed_1"));
```

Note, that because your `Parent` has a virtual destructor, deleting your children through `std::unique_ptr`s to the `Parent` class is safe. No memory will be lost, as you can check with `valgrind` or other memory debuggers.

It is even possible to delete individual elements from your `children` vector as needed:

```
children.erase(children.begin() + 1); // This deletes the second child
```

Comment: Thanks but as I stated I cannot use smart pointers here (so I cannot use this solution) and the intermediate pointer is not what I would like to achieve because my aim would be to reset the `childPtr` to `nullptr` calling the `PointerHandler` class but so it seems not possible so I would implement it manually ^^